# J2ME connection to Server App in java

Tags: netbeans, java-me, java

I am trying to connect an app (made using j2se) running on my PC from an app running on my mobile using GPRS or say WIFI connection but am unable to do it. Can anyone suggest me what can be the issue?

More Info:
My app on PC is continuously listening on port 8000. I am trying to connect it from my mobile app (made in j2me) using IP and port number but I don't know why it is not working. When I try to run both server app and mobile app through my PC, it works using my local IP 192.168.1.2 but not when using my internet IP and through my mobile. Even when connected to wifi I can't connect through local IP or server IP. Can someone help me into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing your internet IP will not get to your desktop IP, unless you modify the router to pass traffic from the internet address/port number to your desktop address/port number.

There's no reason why the wifi enabled phone cannot access your desktop, assuming that they are both on the 192.168.1.xxx network.  Test this by disabling your mobile carriers internet access.  (this means all comm will happen on the 192.168.1.xxx network)